# Как отловить любое исключение

Tags: java

Есть поток, он бегает по командам, эти команды означают некоторые классы, главное чтобы этот поток не прерывался, исключения из этих классов прерывают его, что надо, надо чтобы поток не прерывался, а писать тысячу ловителей исключений я не собираюсь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нашел способ, все исключения наследники **java.lang.Throwable**.
Все работает, исключение выбрасывается, поток не умирает.

```
try{
     if(run.run(i, us, adminPermission))runer = true;
}catch (java.lang.Throwable e){
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Поймать все может базовое исключение [Throwable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) (но рекомендуется ловить от `Exception`, т.к. к `Throwable` относятся исключения, не относящиеся к проблема в логике программы, поэтому обработка их сомнительна, например `java.lang.VirtualMachineError`).

Дерево исключений можно посмотреть в дереве классов: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/package-tree.html

Comment: но лучше так не делать, а остановиться и подумать, чего именно хочется добиться.

Comment: Это, к сожалению, обычная практика, когда требуют, что бы пользователи никогда-никогда не видели ошибок. Тут главное, что бы в этом кетче все и со всеми плюхами уходило обязательно в лог и возможно нужен рестарт (реинициализация) приложения.

Comment: Дело в том что поток прерывается, когда это делать совершенно не требуется! Показывать исключения, показывай, но не прерывай, так как этот поток нужен и другим пользователям. Если поток прервать то другие пользователи ответов на свои команды никогда не получат.

Answer (score 6):

Нет таких исключений, которые не ловятся catch. Исключения выше по иерархии чем `Exception` не рекомендуют ловить(обычно не много вариантов, что при этом можно сделать), но они все равно ловятся catch. Чтобы словить самое верхнее надо ловить `Throwable`.

Но при "При выполнении команды, например, получить элемент 1 из массива размером 0 элементов, вылетит исключение о том, что вышли за пределы и получим поток который остановился." выбрасывается `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` и чтобы его словить достаточно ловить `Exception`.